# Block P2P, FTP, and else on Asus router

Tags: router, firewall

I have a ASUS router RT-AC66U which has a firewall section but I am a bit confused which ports I need to block for P2P and FTP and eventually other services which will drain the connection.

The firewall does have "Filtered ICMP packet types" in case that is a simpler way to setup my firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port numbers:

- Bittorrent Ports 6681-6889 TCP
- FTP Ports 20-21 TCP (20 for data, 21 for control)

P2P can be a little bit tricky. There is nothing stopping some one changing the port to any other port number in order to bypass port blocking.

ICMP blocks devices external from your network from sending ping messages to your router, handy to keep a low profile.

If your wanting to restrict bandwidth usage you may be better of using Quality of service (QoS) which your router supports. This allows you to identify which forms of traffic should have high and low priorities.

There is an acer [video](http://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1008316/) with a guide on how to use QoS for your router.